# SQL Server- find all records within a certain date (not that straightforward!)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

Ok. My SQL is pretty pants so I'm struggling to get my head around this.

I have a table that stores records complete with a time stamp.
What I want, is a list of `uids` where there are 2 or more records for that user within a time frame of 1 second of each other. Maybe I've made it more complicated in my head, just cannot figure it out.

Shortened version of table (pk ignored)

```
    uid date
    1   2015-01-01 10:00:30.020*
    1   2015-01-01 10:00:30.300*
    1   2015-01-01 10:00:30.500*
    1   2015-01-01 10:00:39.000
    1   2015-01-01 10:00:35.000
    1   2015-01-01 10:00:37.800
    2   2015-02-02 12:00:30.000
    2   2015-02-02 14:00:30.000
    2   2015-02-02 15:00:30.000
    2   2015-02-02 18:00:30.000 
    3   2015-03-02 15:00:24.000 
    3   2015-03-02 15:00:20.000 *
    3   2015-03-02 15:00:20.300 *
```

I've marked * next to the records I'd expect to match.
The results list I'd like is just a list of uid, so the result I'd want would just be
1
3

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: To expand on @GordonLinoff's comment, please include the *version* of the database you're using as well. There are functions available in newer releases which can make this much simpler, but if you're using an older release an answer which uses them won't be terribly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `exists`:

```
select distinct uid
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.uid = t.uid and
                    t2.date > t.date and
                    t2.date <= t.date + interval 1 second
             );
```

Note:  The syntax for adding 1 second varies by database.  But the above gives the idea for the logic.

In SQL Server, the syntax is:

```
select distinct uid
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.uid = t.uid and
                    t2.date > t.date and
                    t2.date <= dateadd(second, 1, t.date)
             );
```

EDIT:

Or, in SQL Server 2012+, a faster alternative is to use `lead()` or `lag()`:

```
select distinct uid
from (select t.*, lead(date) over (partition by uid order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where next_date < dateadd(second, 1, date);
```

If you want the *records*, not just the `uid`s, then you need to get both:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by uid order by date) as prev_date,
             lead(date) over (partition by uid order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where next_date <= dateadd(second, 1, date) or
      prev_date >= dateadd(second, -1, date);
```

Comment: Thank you, thats perfect. Would not have figured that one out by myself!